# How to find the Tangent space of a submanifold?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

How can I determine the tangent space $T_pM$, $p\in M$, for the following submanifold?

$$
M:= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|x^2-y=0\}\subset \mathbb{R},\quad p=(1,1)
$$

I figured out, that I can parameterize $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ as $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ x^2 \end{pmatrix}$, but how do I continue?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Take $f: U \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y) = x^2 - y$ at the open $U = \mathbb R^2$, compute $\mathrm {grad} f(p) $ and  remember that $T_pM = [\mathrm {grad} f(p)]^{\perp}$, where $M = f^{-1} (0)$.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathrm{grad} f(x,y)$ at the point $p$?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: Ok.  So $\mathrm{grad}f |_p = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. And do you want to say that $T_p M$ is $\perp$ to $\mathrm{grad}f|_p$? In that case $T_p M$ could be e.g. $\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. (?)

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) for ortthogonal complement.

Comment: So in general $T_p M$ should be $\perp$ $\mathrm{grad}f$, but $T_p M(p)=\mathrm{grad}f(p)$

Comment: There is a perp on $[\mathrm {grad} \, f(p) ]^{\perp}$. That is, $T_pM$ is the orthogonal complement of the subspace generated by $\mathrm{grad} \, f(p) $.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25150/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-kaos).

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y):=x^2-y$$
$$Df(x,y)=(2x,1)$$
$$T_pM=T_{(1,1)}M=\ker Df(1,1)=\ker(2,1)$$

$$\ker (2,1)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:(x,y)\cdot (2,1)=0\}$$
$$\Rightarrow T_{(1,1)}M=\langle(1,-2)\rangle$$